# How to prevent sharing my Paid Application?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have an Already paid App in Playstore. then I want to check user already paid in play store or not. If the user installs apk from other Resource(like Bluetooth, Xender.etc) how to prevent those users who not paid or not Install From Playstore.

Comment: Removed the non-relevant tags, since the post has nothing to do wit in-app-purchases.

Answer (score 0):

It Totally Depends on you and your phone!

Let me Explain You Clearly:-

There is a feature in most of the Paid Third-Party Apps which is called license verification. This is how this whole process works:-

If you buy an app, at the first launch it will require an internet connection, then it will verify a license from play store which you buy at the time you buy the app. Then if the verification is successful the app will launch. But if you share an app with a user who didn’t purchased the same app and tries to open, it will say you to buy the app.

There are another methods by which you can bypass the verification. To do that you will need to root your device (which is very risky) and do some editing with that app(a little complicated).

So Indirectly Yes it can run
But the Direct Answer Is NO.!

Source - My Experience!